# Yet Another "Object doesn't support this property or method" - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just switched my App to run on MVC3 and the Razor view engine, and now I'm getting a JavaScript error.  The thing is, nothing has changed on the JavaScript side of things... it worked before.

Here's the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var json_region = [{"value":365,"label":"Calgary"},{"value":368,"label":"Canmore"},{"value":393,"label":"Edmonton"}]
    $(function() {
        $('#UserRegion').autocomplete({
            source: json_region,
            selectFirst: true,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#RegionID').val( ui.item.value );
                $('#UserRegion').val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Extras/urbannow.js/1"></script>
<script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectfirst.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Assets/Scripts/wmd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Assets/Scripts/showdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is erroring

```
$('#UserRegion').autocomplete({
```

The console says

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

And I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: well for one, your including jquery twice. (jquery-1.4.2.min.js). Also, try doing `Url.Content('file.js')` for including local scripts/images/css. (instead of src='/Assets/).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Not sure how that one slipped by me.  That was it... lol. Post it as an answer and I'll up you're rep.  Boy, it's getting late.. prolly time to unplug (1:00am)

Comment: I am doing Url.Content, I'm just showing the final markup for those who aren't MVC dudes.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - which was it? the jquery twice? or the order. if the latter, accept @Hamish's answer.

Comment: It was the doubling up of the scripts.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - ok, answer added. I couldn't think of anything else to put in the answer. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're including jQuery twice.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `.autocomplete` immediately after including the base jQuery library - which does not include the autocomplete plugin. Fix the order of your script references and make sure the autocomplete plugin is included before you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

load this BEFORE you custom script call

`<script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectfirst.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

or at very best custom code should be after all your JavaScript files.
so , your code should look like something like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Extras/urbannow.js/1"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectfirst.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/wmd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/showdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Assets/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json_region = [{"value":365,"label":"Calgary"},{"value":368,"label":"Canmore"},{"value":393,"label":"Edmonton"}];
    $(function() {
        $('#UserRegion').autocomplete({
            source: json_region,
            selectFirst: true,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#RegionID').val( ui.item.value );
                $('#UserRegion').val( ui.item.label );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate jQuery declaration, check View Source of page